# How to implement conditions in angular5 forms ?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular5

I'm working in angular5 , i'm creating a simple form :

```
 <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Choisir un client : </label>


      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
                     [items]="_listClients"
                      bindLabel ="nom"
                      bindValue ="id"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId">
        </ng-select>

      </div>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Information liées au contrat : </label>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >Date one :  </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm"
               placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateOne">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" for="input-small">Date two : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="date" id="input-small" name="input-small" class="form-control form-control-sm"
               placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateTwo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addProjecToClients()" >Save changes</button>
```

Condition i want to do in this form  : dateOne should always be greater than dateTwo .

So i want to  show an error message  when a user selects dateTwo greater than dateOne before he can submit the form  . 
I think this should happend when he selects the second input 'dateTwo' and then verify the condition above  .

does angular5 provides any helpful libraries or method on how to do that ? 
or should i do it myself  ?

Comment: Angular provides basic providers, the validations which depend on other fields has to be done by you. You can subscribe to value changes of the second date field and compare the values of the first and the second in your custom validator.

Comment: Custom validator ? Is it somthing related to angular ? Or method im going to create to implement this.

Comment: It is angular thing, where you can implement custom logic to validate your forms. There are lots of articles on how to do it.

Comment: Ah okey , i've read some articles about that , but still not able to reach what i want .

Answer (score 0):

You should use FormGrup/FormControls. They provide you validate everything you need, there are some but you can custom them. 
The formControls have a property invalid that indicate you when a form is fine.
I recommend look for information about them.